# Relation in an internal direct product

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is the internal direct product of subgroups $A$ and $B$ of $G$. Define $\pi_A : AB \to A $ by $\pi_A(ab) = a$. Let $H\leq G$ and consider the subset $C_A = \{a \in A \,| \,[a, \pi_A(H)] \leq H\cap A \}$

**Claim**: $C_A$ is a subgroup of $A$

Note that we have $A\cap H \unlhd \pi_A(H)$

$1_G \in C_A$ since $[1_G, \pi_A(H)] = \{1_G\} \leq H \cap A$

Let $x, y \in C_A$. I need to show that $xy^{-1} \in C_A$ i.e $[xy^{-1}, \pi_A(H)] \in A \cap H$

Let $a\in \pi_A(H)$. Since $x, y \in C_A$, by definition of $C_A$, we have that $[x,a] \leq H\cap A$ and $[y,a] \in H\cap A$.

Clearly, $[xy^{-1}, a] \in A$. Then it suffices to show that $[xy^{-1}, a] \in H$

> From above $[x,a] \in H$ and $[y, a] \in H$. I'm not sure how to proceed to show that $[xy^{-1}, a] \in H$

Comment: You should use the standard commutator identities.

Comment: I'm using the notation $[a,b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. Then for $[xy^{-1}, a] = x[y^{-1}, a ]x^{-1}[x,a]$. I know that $[x,a] \in H$. I still run into problems in showing that $x[y^{-1}, a ]x^{-1} \in H$

Comment: You need to prove that $[y^{-1},a] \in H$.

Comment: I'm unable to show this. The closest i'm ending up with is: $[y, a] \in H$ , so that $[a, y] \in H$. Then $yy^{-1}aya^{-1}y^{-1} \in H$ $\implies$ $ y[y^{-1}, a]y^{-1} = [y^{-1}, yay^{-1}] \in H$

Comment: Well then it follows from the fact that $y$ normalizes $\pi_A(H)$.

Comment: I can see why $y$ normalizes $\pi_A(H)$ because $[y, \pi_A(H)] \leq A \cap H \leq \pi_A(H)$.but I'm struggling to use it to even draw a conclusion that $[y^{-1}, a] \in H$

Comment: It follows from $[y^{-1},yay^{-1}] \in H$, because $yay^{-1}$ is an arbitrary element of $C_A$.

Comment: Okay so let $y \in C_A$ then $[y, \pi_A(H)] \leq A \cap H$. I want to show that $y^{-1} \in C_A$. Let $a \in \pi_A(H)$. Then $[y,a] \in [y, \pi_A(H)]$. Now $yy^{-1}[a,y] = [y^{-1}, yay^{-1}] \in [y, \pi_A(H)]$, and so $[y^{-1}, yay^{-1}] \in A \cap H$. However, since $y$ normalizes $\pi_A(H)$, $yay^{-1} = a'$ for some $a'$ in $\pi_A(H)$. Therefore $[y^{-1}, a'] \in [y^{-1}, \pi_A(H)]$. Thus $[y^{-1}, \pi_A(H)] \leq A \cap H$, and so $y^{-1} \in C_A$. Please check if this proof is fine?

Comment: I've also realised that this still doesn't show what I originally needed because I'm not sure how $x[y^{-1}, a]x^{-1} \in H$

Comment: That follows from $x[y^{-1},a]x^{-1} = [xy^{-1}x^{-1},xax^{-1}]$. Sorry but that's my last comment on this!

Comment: But here is another final comment! In general, when you are trying to verify that $H$ is a subgroup of a group, in my experience it is a bad idea to try and show that $x,y \in H \Rightarrow xy^{-1} \in H$. It is generally easier to break it up into two parts and to show $x,y \in H \Rightarrow xy \in H$ and $x \in H \Rightarrow x^{-1} \in H$ separately.

Comment: How do you prove your side note that  $A\cap H \unlhd \pi_A(H)$?